# Unable to create Scala Project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala-ide

I have the Eclipse IDE (Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)). Installed Scala IDE for eclipse version 3.0.x thru eclipe marketplace. But I'm not able to create a scala project , New -> project -> there is no scala option. I have scala 2.11, and sbt in my local machine, and scala is working from command prompt. Is that the problem of eclipse latest version?

Answer (score 1):

Me too! In the eclipse error log (eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/log) I see the following:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.scala-ide.sdt.core [852]
Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.scala-ide.sdt.core [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.scala-ide.sdt.core"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.0.0.m3-2_11-201407241647-33f4f20"; singleton:="true"] because it is exposed to package 'javax.xml.bind' from resources org.eclipse.osgi [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.osgi"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.10.0.v20140606-1445"; singleton:="true"] and javax.xml.bind [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="javax.xml.bind"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.1.9.v201005080401"] via two dependency chains.
```

A bit of searching led to a [conversation in the Scala-IDE google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-ide-user/Kc16Uvus2ls) and also [Eclipse bug 430458](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430458).

The work-around is to add `-clean` to the top of your eclipse.ini file, which somehow changes the order in which dependencies are resolved.

Bonus tip: While you've got eclipse.ini open, up the JVM max heap size to 1024m.

Comment: I think Eclipse Luna version does not support scala IDE at all. You have any idea about it?

Comment: There's currently (Sept 2014) a milestone release that works with Eclipse 4.4 (Luna): http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html#scala-ide-400-milestone-2